# Transform tuple to dict

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

How can I transform tuple like this:

```
(
    ('a', 1),
    ('b', 2)
)
```

to dict:

```
{
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you select the (one and only ATM) answer as your preferred answer?

Answer (score 16):

[Dict](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) constructor can do this for you.

```
dict((
    ('a', 1),
    ('b', 2)
))
```

Comment: Ha, I thought tuple({'a': 1, 'b': 2}) would work vice versa, it gives a tuple of keys instead.

Comment: @Wang Do mydict.items() to get tuple of keys and values.