# Tuple into Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, tuples

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transform tuple to dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553949/transform-tuple-to-dict)

How do I change a list of tuples such as:

```
seq = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

into a dictionary:

```
dicta = { 1:2, 2:4, 5:6 }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
>>> seq = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
>>> dict(seq)
{1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}
```

Isn't python nice :)

As defined in the [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

```
The dict() constructor builds dictionaries directly from lists of key-value pairs stored as tuples.
```