# Turning a tuple of tuples into a dictionary

Tags: python

So I've got tuples inside of tuples, and I would like to turn them into a key: value pair.

```
((1L, 'I.T.'), (2L, 'Project Management'), (3L, 'Creative'), (4L, 'Programming'), (5L, 'Sales'), (6L, 'Administration'), (7L, 'AV'), (8L, 'Human Resources'), (9L, 'Conference Rooms'), (10L, 'Testing'), (11L, 'none'))
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transform tuple to dict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553949/transform-tuple-to-dict) and [List of tuples to dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522446/python-list-of-tuples-to-dictionary)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just pass it to the `dict` constructor/function! It can take any iterable of `(key, value)` tuples and create a dictionary from it.

```
>>> x = ((1L, 'I.T.'), (2L, 'Project Management'), (3L, 'Creative'), (4L, 'Programming'), (5L, 'Sales'), (6L, 'Administration'), (7L, 'AV'), (8L, 'Human Resources'), (9L, 'Conference Rooms'), (10L, 'Testing'), (11L, 'none')
>>> dict(x)
{1L: 'I.T.', 2L: 'Project Management', 3L: 'Creative', 4L: 'Programming', 5L: 'Sales', 6L: 'Administration', 7L: 'AV', 8L: 'Human Resources', 9L: 'Conference Rooms', 10L: 'Testing', 11L: 'none'}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to make the first value (1L, etc) into a string? I can't tell what variable type it is.

EDIT: Apparently it is a long integer.

Comment: It's a long integer, as you can tell by its suffix of `L`.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander: Try `dict((str(key), val) for (key, val) in x)`

Answer (score 2):

By calling `dict` with your tuple as an argument:

```
d = dict(t)
```