# how to change list and tuple into dict in python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

how join tuple list  a dict?

this is what i have:

```
[('a','b'),('c','d'),('e','f')]
```

and this is what i want:

```
{'a':'b','c':'d','e':'f'}
```

thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transform tuple to dict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553949/transform-tuple-to-dict)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just pass the list into the `dict` constructor.  As they are tuples, it will know how to create the dictionary.

```
l = [('a','b'),('c','d'),('e','f')]
d = dict(l)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
dict([('a','b'),('c','d'),('e','f')]
```

should do it